# How to add a button to a class which extends View in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a class B which extends View and i am calling this from a Class A which extends Activity via setContentView.In class B i can draw anything using mouse motion listeners and paint functions. Now i want to add  button on my class B so that i can go  to Class A and do some modifications.
I have tried some codes but that didn't work.

```android
   public class MotionDraw extends View {
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();
    //LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(getContext());


    public MotionDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int x) {
        super(context, attrs);

        //this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        //Button b=new Button(getContext());
        //b.setText("Back"); // better: getContext().getString(R.string.someString);
        //this.addView(b);

                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
        //paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        if(x == 1)
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            some code ...
        }

        // Schedules a repaint.
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For MotionDraw, try to extend RelativeLayout instead of View.

Comment: When i extend it to RelativeLayout i am unable to draw anything on the screen or canvas.